# Change Model input_shape but got an : ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_44 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, generative-adversarial-network

I am new to python and DL.
Please help me to correct the error.
This class was originly created with mnist dataset (28 x 28) I tried to adapt it to my work and the image that I am using are (224 x 224). I changed the input image shape but still have the incompatible shape image and the model still use the old shapes of mnist.
Knowng that the that I am using: X_train=(676, 224, 224)/y_train(676,)/X_test(170, 224, 224)/y_test(170,)

The code :

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Dropout, multiply, concatenate
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, Embedding, ZeroPadding2D, Lambda
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D, Conv2D
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import keras.backend as K

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

    class INFOGAN():
        def __init__(self):
            self.img_rows = 224
            self.img_cols = 224
            self.channels = 1
            self.num_classes = 3
            self.img_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)
            self.latent_dim = 72
    
    
            optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)
            losses = ['binary_crossentropy', self.mutual_info_loss]
    
            # Build and the discriminator and recognition network
            self.discriminator, self.auxilliary = self.build_disk_and_q_net()
    
            self.discriminator.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy'],
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['accuracy'])
    
            # Build and compile the recognition network Q
            self.auxilliary.compile(loss=[self.mutual_info_loss],
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['accuracy'])
    
            # Build the generator
            self.generator = self.build_generator()
    
            # The generator takes noise and the target label as input
            # and generates the corresponding digit of that label
            gen_input = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
            img = self.generator(gen_input)
    
            # For the combined model we will only train the generator
            self.discriminator.trainable = False
    
            # The discriminator takes generated image as input and determines validity
            valid = self.discriminator(img)
            # The recognition network produces the label
            target_label = self.auxilliary(img)
    
            # The combined model  (stacked generator and discriminator)
            self.combined = Model(gen_input, [valid, target_label])
            self.combined.compile(loss=losses,
                optimizer=optimizer)
    
    
        def build_generator(self):
    
            model = Sequential()
    
            model.add(Dense(128 * 7 * 7, activation="relu", input_dim=self.latent_dim))
            model.add(Reshape((7, 7, 128)))
            model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
            model.add(UpSampling2D())
            model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
            model.add(Activation("relu"))
            model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
            model.add(UpSampling2D())
            model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
            model.add(Activation("relu"))
            model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
            model.add(Conv2D(self.channels, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
            model.add(Activation("tanh"))
    
            gen_input = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
            img = model(gen_input)
    
            model.summary()
    
            return Model(gen_input, img)
    
    
        def build_disk_and_q_net(self):
    
            img = Input(shape=self.img_shape)
    
            # Shared layers between discriminator and recognition network
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, input_shape=self.img_shape, padding="same"))
            model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
            model.add(Dropout(0.25))
            model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
            model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0,1),(0,1))))
            model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
            model.add(Dropout(0.25))
            model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
            model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
            model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
            model.add(Dropout(0.25))
            model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
            model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
            model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
            model.add(Dropout(0.25))
            model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
            model.add(Flatten())
    
            img_embedding = model(img)
    
            # Discriminator
            validity = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(img_embedding)
    
            # Recognition
            q_net = Dense(128, activation='relu')(img_embedding)
            label = Dense(self.num_classes, activation='softmax')(q_net)
    
            # Return discriminator and recognition network
            return Model(img, validity), Model(img, label)
    
    
        def mutual_info_loss(self, c, c_given_x):
            """The mutual information metric we aim to minimize"""
            eps = 1e-8
            conditional_entropy = K.mean(- K.sum(K.log(c_given_x + eps) * c, axis=1))
            entropy = K.mean(- K.sum(K.log(c + eps) * c, axis=1))
    
            return conditional_entropy + entropy
    
        def sample_generator_input(self, batch_size):
            # Generator inputs
            sampled_noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, 62))
            sampled_labels = np.random.randint(0, self.num_classes, batch_size).reshape(-1, 1)
            sampled_labels = to_categorical(sampled_labels, num_classes=self.num_classes)
    
            return sampled_noise, sampled_labels
    
        def train(self, epochs, batch_size=128, sample_interval=50):
 
            # Rescale -1 to 1
            X_train = (X_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5) / 127.5
            X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=3)
            y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
    
            # Adversarial ground truths
            valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
            fake = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))
    
            for epoch in range(epochs):
    
                # ---------------------
                #  Train Discriminator
                # ---------------------
    
                # Select a random half batch of images
                idx = np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], batch_size)
                imgs = X_train[idx]
    
                # Sample noise and categorical labels
                sampled_noise, sampled_labels = self.sample_generator_input(batch_size)
                gen_input = np.concatenate((sampled_noise, sampled_labels), axis=1)
    
                # Generate a half batch of new images
                gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(gen_input)
    
                # Train on real and generated data
                d_loss_real = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(imgs, valid)
                d_loss_fake = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, fake)
    
                # Avg. loss
                d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)
    
                # ---------------------
                #  Train Generator and Q-network
                # ---------------------
    
                g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch(gen_input, [valid, sampled_labels])
    
                # Plot the progress
                print ("%d [D loss: %.2f, acc.: %.2f%%] [Q loss: %.2f] [G loss: %.2f]" % (epoch, d_loss[0], 100*d_loss[1], g_loss[1], g_loss[2]))
    
                # If at save interval => save generated image samples
                if epoch % sample_interval == 0:
                    self.sample_images(epoch)
    
        def sample_images(self, epoch):
            r, c = 10, 10
    
            fig, axs = plt.subplots(r, c)
            for i in range(c):
                sampled_noise, _ = self.sample_generator_input(c)
                label = to_categorical(np.full(fill_value=i, shape=(r,1)), num_classes=self.num_classes)
                gen_input = np.concatenate((sampled_noise, label), axis=1)
                gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(gen_input)
                gen_imgs = 0.5 * gen_imgs + 0.5
                for j in range(r):
                    axs[j,i].imshow(gen_imgs[j,:,:,0], cmap='gray')
                    axs[j,i].axis('off')
            fig.savefig("images/%d.png" % epoch)
            plt.close()
    
        def save_model(self):
    
            def save(model, model_name):
                model_path = "saved_model/%s.json" % model_name
                weights_path = "saved_model/%s_weights.hdf5" % model_name
                options = {"file_arch": model_path,
                            "file_weight": weights_path}
                json_string = model.to_json()
                open(options['file_arch'], 'w').write(json_string)
                model.save_weights(options['file_weight'])
    
            save(self.generator, "generator")
            save(self.discriminator, "discriminator")
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        infogan = INFOGAN()
        infogan.train(epochs=50000, batch_size=128, sample_interval=50)
```

the error :

```
 Model: "sequential_23"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_47 (Dense)             (None, 6272)              457856    
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_11 (Reshape)         (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_87 (Batc (None, 7, 7, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_40 (UpSampling (None, 14, 14, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_99 (Conv2D)           (None, 14, 14, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_42 (Activation)   (None, 14, 14, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_88 (Batc (None, 14, 14, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_41 (UpSampling (None, 28, 28, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_100 (Conv2D)          (None, 28, 28, 64)        73792     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_43 (Activation)   (None, 28, 28, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_89 (Batc (None, 28, 28, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_101 (Conv2D)          (None, 28, 28, 1)         577       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_44 (Activation)   (None, 28, 28, 1)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 681,089
Trainable params: 680,449
Non-trainable params: 640
_________________________________________________________________
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 224, 224, 1) for input Tensor("input_22:0", shape=(None, 224, 224, 1), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28, 28, 1).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 224, 224, 1) for input Tensor("conv2d_95_input:0", shape=(None, 224, 224, 1), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28, 28, 1).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-60a1c6b0bc8b> in <module>()
    225 
    226 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 227     infogan = INFOGAN()
    228     infogan.train(epochs=50000, batch_size=128, sample_interval=50)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    214                 ' incompatible with the layer: expected axis ' + str(axis) +
    215                 ' of input shape to have value ' + str(value) +
--> 216                 ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))
    217     # Check shape.
    218     if spec.shape is not None:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_44 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 115200 but received input with shape [None, 2048]
```

Comment: I don't really know much about generative-adversarial networks, but it seems to me that you load the dataset with `mnist.load_data()` in train function, in which case the images have a shape (28, 28, 1), and then you feed them to the discriminator that you built expecting the shape (224, 224, 1). I suggest you print the shape of X_train in your train function just before you feed it to the model. Let me know what you found out!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ladislav, actully I deleted the line that load the mnist dataset before running the code. I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to change the architecture of the generator. The generator's output shape and the discriminator's input shape have to match. That's what causing the error.

To fix it, you need to fix the architecture. The generator produces images in shape (28, 28, 1), but you want (224, 224, 1). The shape the architecture produces is the result of the architecture itself and its parameters.

So I added two Upsampling layers and changed the size of the other layers to match the discriminator's output.

Also, I removed ZeroPadding2D layer from discriminator, since it made the shape odd (15, 15, ..), and therefore it was impossible to match the same size in the generator.

Here's the code:

```
def build_generator(self):

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(512 * 14 * 14, activation="relu", input_dim=self.latent_dim))
    model.add(Reshape((14, 14, 512)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(self.channels, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation("tanh"))

    gen_input = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
    img = model(gen_input)

    model.summary()

    return Model(gen_input, img)


def build_disk_and_q_net(self):

    img = Input(shape=self.img_shape)

    # Shared layers between discriminator and recognition network
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, input_shape=self.img_shape, padding="same"))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
    #model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0,1),(0,1))))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Flatten())
    
    
    model.summary()

    img_embedding = model(img)

    # Discriminator
    validity = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(img_embedding)

    # Recognition
    q_net = Dense(128, activation='relu')(img_embedding)
    label = Dense(self.num_classes, activation='softmax')(q_net)

    # Return discriminator and recognition network
    return Model(img, validity), Model(img, label)
```

And the summaries:

```
Model: "sequential_14"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_53 (Conv2D)           (None, 112, 112, 64)      640       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_28 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_28 (Dropout)         (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_54 (Conv2D)           (None, 56, 56, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_29 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_29 (Dropout)         (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_46 (Batc (None, 56, 56, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_55 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_30 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_30 (Dropout)         (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_47 (Batc (None, 28, 28, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_56 (Conv2D)           (None, 14, 14, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_31 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_31 (Dropout)         (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_48 (Batc (None, 14, 14, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_7 (Flatten)          (None, 100352)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 1,553,408
Trainable params: 1,551,616
Non-trainable params: 1,792
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential_15"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_31 (Dense)             (None, 100352)            7325696   
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_7 (Reshape)          (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_49 (Batc (None, 14, 14, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_18 (UpSampling (None, 28, 28, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_57 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 256)       1179904   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_25 (Activation)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_50 (Batc (None, 28, 28, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_19 (UpSampling (None, 56, 56, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_58 (Conv2D)           (None, 56, 56, 128)       295040    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_26 (Activation)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_51 (Batc (None, 56, 56, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_20 (UpSampling (None, 112, 112, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_59 (Conv2D)           (None, 112, 112, 64)      73792     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_27 (Activation)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_52 (Batc (None, 112, 112, 64)      256       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_21 (UpSampling (None, 224, 224, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_60 (Conv2D)           (None, 224, 224, 1)       577       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_28 (Activation)   (None, 224, 224, 1)       0         
=================================================================
Total params: 8,878,849
Trainable params: 8,876,929
Non-trainable params: 1,920
_________________________________________________________________
```

**EDIT:**

Because you decreased the number of classes from 10 to 3, therefore you have to change the latent_dim parameter to 65. Notice that the method `sample_generator_input` generates noise of size 62 and labels of size number of classes, which then concatenates (size becomes 62 + 3 = 65).

The generator is defined to accept input_dim of `self.latent_dim`, it would be appropriate to calculate the `latent_dim` in the constructor based on the number of classes instead: `self.latent_dim = 62 + self.num_classes`.

Moreover, in method `sample_images`, there are hardcoded magical numbers.
How can one know what it means? I mean this: `r, c = 10, 10`.
I assume that it means number of classes. Since you changed it from 10 to 3 in your example, I suggest you change the line to:

```
    r, c = self.num_classes, self.num_classes
```

Overall, the code is badly written and if you change a constant then it all breaks. Be careful when copying full pieces of code. Make sure you understand each and every part of it before copying.

Here's the full code:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Dropout, multiply, concatenate
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, Embedding, ZeroPadding2D, Lambda
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D, Conv2D
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import keras.backend as K

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

class INFOGAN():
    def __init__(self):
        self.img_rows = 224
        self.img_cols = 224
        self.channels = 1
        self.num_classes = 3
        self.img_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)
        self.latent_dim = 62 + self.num_classes


        optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)
        losses = ['binary_crossentropy', self.mutual_info_loss]

        # Build and the discriminator and recognition network
        self.discriminator, self.auxilliary = self.build_disk_and_q_net()

        self.discriminator.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy'],
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['accuracy'])

        # Build and compile the recognition network Q
        self.auxilliary.compile(loss=[self.mutual_info_loss],
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['accuracy'])

        # Build the generator
        self.generator = self.build_generator()

        # The generator takes noise and the target label as input
        # and generates the corresponding digit of that label
        gen_input = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        img = self.generator(gen_input)

        # For the combined model we will only train the generator
        self.discriminator.trainable = False

        # The discriminator takes generated image as input and determines validity
        valid = self.discriminator(img)
        # The recognition network produces the label
        target_label = self.auxilliary(img)

        # The combined model  (stacked generator and discriminator)
        self.combined = Model(gen_input, [valid, target_label])
        self.combined.compile(loss=losses,
            optimizer=optimizer)


    def build_generator(self):

        model = Sequential()

        model.add(Dense(512 * 14 * 14, activation="relu", input_dim=self.latent_dim))
        model.add(Reshape((14, 14, 512)))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        
        model.add(UpSampling2D())
        model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        
        model.add(UpSampling2D())
        model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        
        model.add(UpSampling2D())
        model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        
        model.add(UpSampling2D())
        model.add(Conv2D(self.channels, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
        model.add(Activation("tanh"))

        gen_input = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        img = model(gen_input)

        model.summary()

        return Model(gen_input, img)


    def build_disk_and_q_net(self):

        img = Input(shape=self.img_shape)

        # Shared layers between discriminator and recognition network
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, input_shape=self.img_shape, padding="same"))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
        #model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0,1),(0,1))))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(Flatten())
        
        
        model.summary()

        img_embedding = model(img)

        # Discriminator
        validity = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(img_embedding)

        # Recognition
        q_net = Dense(128, activation='relu')(img_embedding)
        label = Dense(self.num_classes, activation='softmax')(q_net)
        
        print(label.shape)

        # Return discriminator and recognition network
        return Model(img, validity), Model(img, label)


    def mutual_info_loss(self, c, c_given_x):
        """The mutual information metric we aim to minimize"""
        eps = 1e-8
        conditional_entropy = K.mean(- K.sum(K.log(c_given_x + eps) * c, axis=1))
        entropy = K.mean(- K.sum(K.log(c + eps) * c, axis=1))

        return conditional_entropy + entropy

    def sample_generator_input(self, batch_size):
        # Generator inputs
        sampled_noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, 62))
        sampled_labels = np.random.randint(0, self.num_classes, batch_size).reshape(-1, 1)
        print(sampled_labels)
        sampled_labels = to_categorical(sampled_labels, num_classes=self.num_classes)

        return sampled_noise, sampled_labels

    def train(self, epochs, batch_size=128, sample_interval=50):
 
        X_train = np.ones([batch_size, 224, 224])
        y_train = np.zeros([batch_size,])
        # Rescale -1 to 1
        X_train = (X_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5) / 127.5
        X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=3)
        y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)

        # Adversarial ground truths
        valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
        fake = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))

        for epoch in range(epochs):

            # ---------------------
            #  Train Discriminator
            # ---------------------

            # Select a random half batch of images
            idx = np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], batch_size)
            imgs = X_train[idx]

            # Sample noise and categorical labels
            sampled_noise, sampled_labels = self.sample_generator_input(batch_size)
            gen_input = np.concatenate((sampled_noise, sampled_labels), axis=1)

            print(sampled_labels.shape, batch_size)
            # Generate a half batch of new images
            gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(gen_input)

            # Train on real and generated data
            d_loss_real = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(imgs, valid)
            d_loss_fake = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, fake)

            # Avg. loss
            d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)

            # ---------------------
            #  Train Generator and Q-network
            # ---------------------

            g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch(gen_input, [valid, sampled_labels])

            # Plot the progress
            print ("%d [D loss: %.2f, acc.: %.2f%%] [Q loss: %.2f] [G loss: %.2f]" % (epoch, d_loss[0], 100*d_loss[1], g_loss[1], g_loss[2]))

            # If at save interval => save generated image samples
            if epoch % sample_interval == 0:
                self.sample_images(epoch)

    def sample_images(self, epoch):
        r, c = self.num_classes, self.num_classes

        fig, axs = plt.subplots(r, c)
        for i in range(c):
            sampled_noise, _ = self.sample_generator_input(c)
            label = to_categorical(np.full(fill_value=i, shape=(r,1)), num_classes=self.num_classes)
            gen_input = np.concatenate((sampled_noise, label), axis=1)
            gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(gen_input)
            gen_imgs = 0.5 * gen_imgs + 0.5
            for j in range(r):
                axs[j,i].imshow(gen_imgs[j,:,:,0], cmap='gray')
                axs[j,i].axis('off')
        fig.savefig("images/%d.png" % epoch)
        plt.close()

    def save_model(self):

        def save(model, model_name):
            model_path = "saved_model/%s.json" % model_name
            weights_path = "saved_model/%s_weights.hdf5" % model_name
            options = {"file_arch": model_path,
                        "file_weight": weights_path}
            json_string = model.to_json()
            open(options['file_arch'], 'w').write(json_string)
            model.save_weights(options['file_weight'])

        save(self.generator, "generator")
        save(self.discriminator, "discriminator")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    infogan = INFOGAN()
    infogan.train(epochs=50000, batch_size=8, sample_interval=50)
```

Comment: I copied the modifications that you made but while running the train fonction I got an other Value error in the code line gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(gen_input). The error is : WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 72) for input Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(None, 72), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (32, 65). ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 72 but received input with shape [32, 65]

Comment: @Eko Does the original code work for you without errors? Because if I try to run your original code with image shape (28, 28, 1), I receive the same error.

Comment: I figured that you also changed number of classes, and that's also causing shape incompatibilities.

Comment: yes it works very well without error. In the original code he used: self.img_rows = 28, self.img_cols = 28, self.channels = 1, self.num_classes = 10 and inside the train fonction, he uploaded the mnist dataset with this line : (X_train, y_train), (_, _) = mnist.load_data(). The only changes that I made is the shape of the image, the number of classe and I uploaded my own dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help